# Routing mach with regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, constraints

**I have this in RouteConfig.cs:**

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "Login/{token}/{nameII}",
    new { controller = "InicioPareja", action = "Login"
    //, token = UrlParameter.Optional, nameII = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
    ,new {token = @"/[0-9a-f]+/i{12}",nameII = @"^\w{1,20}$/" }
);
```

If I comment the constrain/regex `(...token = @"/[0-9a-f ...)` line, everything is OK.
It's match with the URL: `.../Login/017E8BCADE06/Ana`

**Controller has the parameters:** 017E8BCADE06 and Ana

But with the regex say: Not found.  And commenting/uncommenting line: ...UrlParameter.Optional..., the same.
Obviously, even it doesn't executes the controller.
Even with the RouteDebugger doesn't match anything and it helps me nothing.

Any idea?
Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Does it work if you change regex to `[0-9a-fA-F]+` ? In this case you regex is just case-sensetive.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't solve the problem.  The problem is the url match, not regex.  But I'll add your regex.

Comment: `@"(?i)[0-9a-f]{12}"` should match the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this out:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "Login/{token}/{nameII}",
    new { controller = "InicioPareja", action = "Login"
    //, token = UrlParameter.Optional, nameII = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
    ,new {token = @"[0-9a-f]{12}",nameII = @"^\w{1,20}$" }
);
```